# How do I get the result of multiple Async Tasks Running in the background at one place?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a class which is used to fetch Geocodes from an API when I pass in the String location. The problem is, that I need both the origin and destination geocodes before I start my map activity. How do I synchronize this task?

Comment: @kunal kalra Please share the code first.

Comment: use `Inerface` or `BroadcastReceiver `